# AttributeError: 'CollectionReference' object has no attribute 'doc'

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import firestore
import traceback    
import json
cred = credentials.Certificate(constants.path_to_json)
default_app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
other_app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, name='other')
db = firestore.client()
match_id = 'blala'
pool_id = 'pidxyz'
cont_team_id = '229'

doc_ref = db.collection('match-pools')\
        .document(match_id)\
        .collection('pid')\
        .document(pool_id)\
        .collection('contestant-teams')\
        .document(cont_team_id)

def create_counter(ref, num_shards):
    batch = db.batch()
    print(batch)
    # Initialize the counter document
    batch.set(ref, { 'num_shards': num_shards })
    # Initialize each shard with count=0
    for i in range(0, num_shards):
        shardRef = ref.collection('shards').document(str(i))
        batch.set(shardRef, { count: 0 })
    # Commit the write batch
    return batch.commit()

create_counter(doc_ref, 5)
```

> AttributeError: 'CollectionReference' object has no attribute 'doc'

Comment: Method name is `document()`, not `doc()`. You use it correctly when initializing `doc_ref`, but `create_counter()` method doesn't do it right.

Comment: thanks, silly mistake. closing the issue.

Comment: @HiranyaJayathilaka Now I am stuck with another issue, maybe you can take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55898357/what-is-the-python-equivalent-of-this

Answer (score 4):

Method name is `document()`, not `doc()`. You use it correctly when initializing `doc_ref`, but `create_counter()` method doesn't do it right.

*Copy of comment by Hiranya Jayathilaka since it is the correct answer. OP, you can accept this comment to close the question.*