# How to increment Firestore field value in python?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

`shard_ref.update("count", firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1));`

I am looking for way to increment and update in python, I am not abe to even update it with a predefined value in python. the doc doesn't specify any python samples.
I am using `firebase_admin` sdk like this,

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import firestore
```

for more check docs https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/counters

Comment: Feature request in `open` status here: https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/7533

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately (to me it just doesn't feel right), adding support for transforms in your codebase means you have to use [google-cloud-firestore](https://googleapis.dev/python/firestore/latest/index.html) next to `firebase_admin`.

You can then use [Transforms](https://googleapis.dev/python/firestore/latest/transforms.html) such as `Increment`, `ArrayRemove`, etc.

Sample code:

```
from google.cloud.firestore_v1 import Increment
# assuming shard_ref is a firestore document reference
shard_ref.update({'count': Increment(1)})
```

Comment: "firebase-admin" comes with "google-cloud-firestore"

Answer (score 0):

another option is use Firebase Realtime Database URL as a REST endpoint. ( All we need to do is append .json to the end of the URL and send a request from our favorite HTTPS client)

for your case, use conditional request. explanation and example described at https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/save-data#section-conditional-requests